# Very long string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, text, size

I need to use a list of approximately 320 000 words with JavaScript and to store each word in an array.

I tried to simply store the list in a string variable with this format :

```
var list = "word1\n"+
    "word2\n"+
    //...
    "word319999\n"+
    "word320000";

var dict = list.split("\n");
```

But it doesn't work with this method as there are too many words (if I decrease the amount of words, this method works, but it's not useful for me).

How one could use such a long list of words in JavaScript ?

Comment: This sounds like your approach to the problem might be flawed. What is the bigger picture here?

Comment: I'm using the Google Chrome extension Tampermonkey to write a script that will display a text field and ask for a pattern. When I write this pattern, the script should search for all the words containing this pattern and display a list of them to me.

Comment: And that list of word shall be hardcoded to the extension? No possibility to query a server for matches?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. I don't own the webpage the script will be executed on. But I own some server that can execute PHP if it is of any help.

Comment: In an extension you could contact another server. It does not matter, which page the script is run upon, as the execution just happens on the client side. So general scenario: You still ask for the pattern, but then send the pattern to a script on *your* server, which does the processing and returns a list of word. Inside the server script you could use a database to do the heavy work

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. I just wonder how to communicate with my server in JavaScript.

Comment: Since you seem to have all the words already, why not just put them in a dictionary to start?

Comment: @David: You mean a JavaScript object ? Like so : `var dict = {"word1", "word2", "...", "word320000"};` ? I just tried this and it seems to have the same size limitation than the String objects.

Comment: Order all the words then split them into 26 different dictionaries. If that doesn't work, 52, or 78. Basically, make `26 * n` dictionaries, and then one letter per `n` dictionaries. Might help speed up the searches too, since you can essentially narrow the list to 1/26 of the original search size.

Comment: @David: Well I tried to directly write the JavaScript array like so : `var dict = ["word1", "word2", "...", "word320000"];`, and it works, arrays don't seem to have the same size limit.

Comment: @David: It is a good idea but the pattern is not dependent of the first letter of the word. For example, "UU" pattern is in "VACUUM". I used the `string.indexOf(pattern)` function but it is a bit slow, I might have to find a faster method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?